# Conform with File Hierarchy Standard on Linux: where to put binary examples for a library?

Tags: packaging, sample, deb, fhs

I am creating a debian package for a library and would like to install binary samples.
I was thinking to put them under `/usr/share/libname`, but lintian complains (arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share). According FHS this correct, but where can put those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not correct according to the FHS; `/usr/share` is quite explicitly for "architecture-independent data". `/usr/lib` is the arch-dependent equivalent, and that's probably what you want (`/usr/lib/libname`).

See http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLIBLIBRARIESFORPROGRAMMINGANDPA for details.

Comment: Damn - I ignored usr/lib, because the samples are no libs! Thanks again ;).